# Insert results of filtered table back into original table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have an original table `#TEMP_TABLE` with an integer indexed field `ID` which I need to filter by joining it to another table `FILTER` on a related field `ID_R` which in turn is filtered by some conditions. Those conditions are supplied in a `WHILE` loop. At the end of the loop I need filtered result back in the original #TEMP_TABLE.

So currently I am doing something like

```
WHILE [loop condition]
BEGIN
   SELECT #TEMP_TABLE.ID INTO #TMP_FILTERED_TABLE
   FROM #TEMP_TABLE INNER JOIN FILTER ON #TEMP_TABLE.ID = FILTER.ID_R
   WHERE FILTER.FIELD1 = [parameter1 from loop] AND FILTER.FIELD2 = [parameter2 from loop]

   TRUNCATE TABLE #TEMP_TABLE

   INSERT INTO #TEMP_TABLE (ID)
   SELECT ID FROM #TMP_FILTERED_TABLE

   DROP TABLE #TMP_FILTERED_TABLE
END -- END LOOP
```

FILTER table is quite huge so JOIN there performs a double task - it limits FILTER to a smaller subset by ID and then when FILTER is filtered by its own WHERE clause limits the output result. As loop progresses result grows smaller because #TEMP_TABLE grows smaller.

The requirement is after the loop have final result in the original #TEMP_TABLE.

Is there a better, more optimal, optimized way to do this?

Comment: Oook... Would the downvoters please comment reason for downvotes? Is it "what have you tried?" or "not a programming question" or "offtopic because". Please specify,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using Filtered_table, can you not just use

```
 delete t 
 from #temp_table t
      INNER JOIN FILTER ON t.ID = FILTER.ID_R
      WHERE NOT (FILTER.FIELD1 = [parameter1 from loop] 
                 AND FILTER.FIELD2 = [parameter2 from loop])
```

Comment: Thanks! I was thinking about DELETE but couldn't pinpoint correct query and this one looks like will do the trick, I will it a try. Also is there an inexpensive way to check after DELETE if #TEMP_TABLE has no more records? When using original INSERT I could just check @@ROWCOUNT - and exit the loop.

Comment: @YuriyGalanter If a count(*) is too expensive, you could do try a `select exists` or perhaps a `select top 1` into a variable and check for it being null (reset it to null before the select)